# TeamCity - REST API - Last successful build

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.1

I'm trying to get the **latest** successful build.

This request returns *all of the successful builds* for a specified `buildType` (as `BUILDTYPE` below).

```
/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/?locator=buildType:BUILDTYPE,status:SUCCESS
```

Is there a way to further filter out to get the single latest successful build of the corresponding `buildType`?

**TeamCity Version:** Professional 9.1.3 (build 37176)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Adding a count of 1 should work:

```
/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/?locator=buildType:BUILDTYPE,status:success,count:1
```

Comment: Re-read my question please. What you've suggested returns all of the successful builds...I want the single latest successful build of the corresponding `buildType`

Comment: The latest build is always stacked at the top of the response, right?
It seems to work, thanks!

Comment: How do we get the status of latest executed build on the buildtypeid, for instance the latest one is still running or is queued or it has failed.

Comment: This does not work with TeamCity 2017.1.3 (build 46961). I also tried with passing the api version like this: `httpAuth/app/rest/9.1/` with no luck!

Answer (score 5):

You can get the id of the last successful build by executing the following request:

```
/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/BUILDTYPE/builds/status:success/id
```

Then you can query the build itself:

```
/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/?locator=buildType:BUILDTYPE,id:BUILD_ID
```

Comment: It seems the first request you've given is not supported: `Error has occurred during request processing (Not Acceptable).`

Comment: I have tested it on our [public server](https://teamcity.jetbrains.com/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/TeamCityPluginsByJetBrains_VisualStudioOnlineIssueTrackin_TeamCityVsOnlineWork_3/builds/status:success/id). If the error persists, would you mind filing an issue in [the bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com) ?

Comment: What TeamCity version are you on? :)

Comment: How do we get the status of latest executed build on the buildtypeid, for instance the latest one is still running or is queued or it has failed.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl http://username:password@ipofserver:8111/app/rest/builds\?buildType\=BUILDTYPE\&count\=1 --header "Accept: application/json"
```

Use this in zsh will work, it's already escaped special words with '\'